# FFMPEG buffer underflow

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, screen-capture

I'm recording a video with `FFMPEG` and getting some wierd message in the process

```
[mpeg @ 01011c80] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 01011c80] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=236198 size=412405
[mpeg @ 01011c80] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=238239 size=412405
```

and I have no idea how to deal with it. Here's my code for adding frames

```
void ofxFFMPEGVideoWriter::addFrame(const uint8_t* pixels)
{
    memcpy(picture_rgb24->data[0], pixels, size);

    sws_scale(swsContext, picture_rgb24->data, picture_rgb24->linesize, 0, codecContext->height, picture->data, picture->linesize);

    AVPacket packet = { 0 };
    int got_packet;
    av_init_packet(&packet);

    int ret = avcodec_encode_video2(codecContext, &packet, picture, &got_packet);
    if (ret < 0) qDebug() << "Error encoding video frame: " << ret;

    if (!ret && got_packet && packet.size)
    {
        packet.stream_index = videoStream->index;
        ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(formatContext, &packet);
    }

    picture->pts += av_rescale_q(1, videoStream->codec->time_base, videoStream->time_base);
}
```

The file itself seems to be fine, and readable, but that message is really bugging me. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Unless your files will be played on a hardware MPEG-1 player, you can ignore it.